# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Cannot open connection at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

```
**hibernate.cfg.xml:**:
```

**SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();**
//above query which i used in main class is also not working ,but it shows  same thing...??

> this is my configuration file.....how can i ran ouot this problem...??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"> 
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property> <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/name</property> <property name="connection.user">root</property> 
<property name="connection.password">tiger</property> 
<property name="show_sql">true</property> 
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property> 
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
 <mapping resource="Pojo.hbm.xml" />
 </session-factory>
 </hibernate-configuration>
------------------------------------------------------------------------


**pojo.hbm.xml:**
```

> this is my hibernate mapping file.....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"  
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">  

<hibernate-mapping>

<class  name="com.firoz.pojo.Pojo" table="name">
<id name="eid" column="id" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
<property name="ename" column="name" type="java.lang.String" />
<property name="sal" column="sal" type="java.lang.Integer" />

</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
------------------------------------------------------------------------

***when i run this program i getting error like***
------------------------------------------------------------------------
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:29)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:420)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1326)
    at com.firoz.main.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:18)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'name'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:978)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:870)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4332)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1258)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2234)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2265)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2064)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:790)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:395)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:417)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: I guess the problem is with your connection string, check if database with `name` exists

Comment: thank you vishrant.................